# Appium: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command in MAC OS

Tags: javascript, ios, selenium-chromedriver, appium

**Full error:**

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.

**Original error:**

> No Chromedriver found that can automate Chrome '82.0.4085'. See
> https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md
> for more details. You could also try to enable automated chromedrivers
> download server feature

**My code:**
[Here is the error in photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVdZL.jpg)

```
{
  "deviceName": "abc",
  "platformName": "android",
  "browserName": "chrome",
  "chromeDriverExecutable": "/Users/mahmudulhasan/Documents/other/chromedriver"
}
```

Comment: Facing the same issue... did you get any solution?

Comment: though i updated chromedriver file in appium-chromedriver folder in node modules, still getting the same issue... any suggestions would be highly appreciated...